# objective C - How to use sqlite to access shared container (app share extension)

Tags: ios, sqlite, ios8-extension

I am trying to add libsqlite3.dylib in Project linking library, but getting error like
_sqlite3_close", referenced from.

How to provide the directory path for shared container to access?

Please provide step by step details.

Comment: That is not a complete or coherent error message. Please include the complete error message.